# Call function after routeconfig in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have done a route configuration with MVC. The route is so defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Box",
   url: "boxes/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Boxes", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The problem is that when i call a javascript function from the view Boxes, all the function i call are redirected to the Index function.

For example, if i call `var url = "/Boxes/ReturnPrice";` the site don't call this function but the index function.

The index function in boxesController is so defined:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

//Code here

return view();

}
```

Comment: Where's the route for `ReturnPrice`?

Comment: Is a function in boxesController called public ActionResult returnPrice but the code never is called. If i don't use routeconfig i can call this function correctly

Comment: Right, so you need to add the route for it. Looks like you only have the route for index.

Comment: But i call it from javascript. How can i route it? It has the same url of the index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `/Boxes/ReturnPrice` , It matches your "Box" route definition. the framework will map "`ReturnPrice`" from the url to the `id` parameter !

You need to define a route constraint which tells that your id property is of type int ( I assume it is int in your case) . Also you need to make sure that you have a generic route definition exists to handle your normal requests with the format `controllername/actionmethodname`.

You can define the route constraint when defining the route using regex.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Box",
   url: "boxes/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Boxes", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this `Boxes/ReturnPrice` will go to ReturnPrice action method while `Boxes/5` will go to Index action method with value 5 set to Id param.

Comment: Ok i have understand and it is correct, but in another page i need to have the name as parameter as string. How can i do this with a string?

Comment: I have added another routeConfig only for boxes/ReturnPrice and now it works fine. Thank you very much!